# Sum of product partitions of divisors

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $M(n)$ be the the set of the multiplicative partitions of $n$, and let $D(n)$ be the set of the sum of the multiplicative partitions of the divisors of $n$.

eg $M(30)=\{\{30\},\{2,15\},\{3, 10\}, \{5, 6\}, \{2, 3, 5\}\}$

and $D(30)=\{30,17,13,11,10\}$

This can be normalised and plotted by pairing up the ordered set $\log D$ with $x=\{1,2,3\dots\}$, which in this case would yield the plot points $\{\{1,\log10\},\{2,\log11\},\{3,\log13\},\{4,\log17\},\{5,\log30\}\}$.

It appears that  these points are normally distributed:

[image]

(plot of $\log F(6\ 469\ 693\ 230)$), which is fairly obvious intuitively. Is this an incarnation of the [Erdős–Kac theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem)? Likely proving this would be difficult?

## Notes

*Mathematica* code for [primorials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Primorial.html) (which are easiest to compute for large $n$):

```
<< Combinatorica`
primorial = 10;
a = Range[primorial];
b = Thread[a -> Prime[a]];
c = Apply[Times, SetPartitions[a] /. b, {2}];
ListLinePlot[Log[Sort[Map[Total[c[[#]]] &, Range[Length[c]]]]]]
```

General code for any $n$:

```
n = 1000;
α[1, r_] := α[1, r] = 1;  α[n_, r_] := α[n, r] = 
Module[{s, i}, s = Select[Divisors[n], 1 < # <= r &];
Sum[α[n/s[[i]], s[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[s]}]]; β[n_]:= α[n, n]; γ[lst_, p_] := 
Module[{t, i, j}, Union[Flatten[Table[t = lst[[i]]; t[[j]] = p*t[[j]];
Sort[t], {i, Length[lst]}, {j, Length[lst[[i]]]}], 1], 
Table[Sort[Append[lst[[i]], p]], {i, Length[lst]}]]];
δ[n_] := Module[{i, j, p, e, lst = {{}}},{p, e} = Transpose[FactorInteger[n]];
Do[lst = γ[lst, p[[i]]], {i, Length[p]}, {j, e[[i]]}]; lst];
ListLinePlot[Log[Sort[Map[Total[δ[n][[#]]] &, Range[β[n]]]]], 
InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[Colossally abundant numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ColossallyAbundantNumber.html) also produce relatively smooth plots:

```
\[NumberSign][n_] := Times @@ Prime[Range[n]];
n = 2^3 3^1 \[NumberSign][5];
```

Comment: $F(30)$ appears to be a set, so what are you plotting?

Comment: The (ordered) set mapped against $x=1,2,3\dots$

Comment: Does that mean for $F(30)$ you are plotting the pairs $(1,\log 10),(2, \log 11), (3,\log 13),(4, \log 17),(5, \log 30)?$

Comment: Question updated now